# How do I attach compression fitting to copper pipe that is bent?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I need to replace a compression union on some copper pipe that runs to my water heater.

I cut the pipe as close to the old union as I could, then tried to slide the compression fittings onto the pipe ends that will be joined. The water heater side fit perfectly into the compression fitting, but the other end is at the end of a long bend and would not fit into the fitting.

I can't replace the pipe that is bent without having to replace multiple connections. How do I get this bent pipe into the compression fitting?

Comment: You are better off replacing the line farther back, sorry I do not have good news for you. A picture of your situation would helpful to confirm that.

Comment: In my opinion, replacing the soft copper is worth your time anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to cut the pipe between the bend and the first splice and attach a compression union there, so I didn't have to replace any of the splices further down the line. My only problem is I don't have a pipe bender, I ended up bending the two foot section(used to replace what I cut off) by hand as a quick fix just to get the hot water heater running again, but I'll need to replace that soon because it's pretty kinky right now.